# sys.dm_tran_current_transaction. How unique is transaction_id

Tags: sql-server

I am capturing the transaction_id from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction in my audit triggers.  What I would like to know is the uniqueness of transaction_id.  The documentation only says "Transaction ID of the current snapshot".

I can only assume that this "ID" will be reused at a later time, but i would appreciate some confirmation on this.

Comment: Interesting question, this [wikipedia page looks relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#Logging_and_Transaction)

Comment: I don't think it's likely that ID will be reused that you would ever notice.  The transaction_id is a bigint which can go up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  It also seems to increments up only.

Comment: @Zhenny, please note that the ID will be reused.  transaction_id is reset on SQL being restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Reference details can be checked at this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/11/sql-server-interesting-observation-of-dmv-of-active-transactions-and-dmv-of-current-transactions/)**

[image]

Comment: This does not show that transaction-ids are unique or not unique. It is unrelated to this question.

Comment: I agree. The fact that the datatype is a bigint is helpful, but there doesn't appear to be any documentation stating that the transaction id is unique for the life of the database.

Comment: Transaction_id restarts at 0 after a server restart.

Comment: Thanks @abcdefghi  After performing a restart of SQL Server and logging a new transaction the transaction_id is near zero where before the last audited transaction_id was in the 2-million.

Answer (score 3):

@abcdefghi's answer is good, but just to add to it;

- Transaction_id is the same within a transaction,
- outside an explicit transaction, transaction_id updates on each batch,
- transaction_id resets when the server resets, so you will encounter the same transaction_id over time.

What this leads to is that you can't use transaction_id in audit tables, because of this scenario;

audit record inserted with transaction_id = 42
   sql server reset
   ... 41 new batches executed ...
   audit record inserted with transaction_id = 42

Also, you can't use transaction_id like a timestamp (higher values do not imply later changes_ and you can't say that the same ID implies the same transaction.